# How do I search in Ubuntu Mate's "Software Boutique"?

Tags: package-management, software-boutique

I have just installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04, and I'm trying to use the Software Boutique to install some things.

I see the categories, but how do I search for specific things?

I tried just typing the packages I want, this did not do any thing. I tried clicking around, I didn't not find a search feature.

Comment: You could use Synaptic package manager instead -- it has a great search feature and should be installed by default in Ubuntu MATE. The Software Boutique is just a small list of carefully-selected packages, and doesn't necessarily need great search capabilities.

Comment: Sure, I could install something else, and I do like synaptic. If i can use the system default effectively, I would rather do that.

Answer (score 4):

The Software Boutique contains only a small selection of software applications, and is meant to be browsed, not searched. If you want a wider, searchable selection, you have to install Gnome Software or Ubuntu Software Center. The Boutique itself says as much on the front page:

> If you can't find what you're looking for, install one of the software
>   centers to explore the complete Ubuntu software catalog.

Answer (score 2):

Start Ubuntu MATE Welcome and click "Subscribe to updates" in the top right portion of the window. Welcome will now update to the latest version, including updating the Software Boutique.

After the update is complete start Software Boutique and you will now find a spy glass icon in the top right portion of the window. Click that and start searching ☺️