# Ubuntu 16.04 (Mate) Software Center

Tags: software-installation, software-center, ubuntu-mate

For the first time I am using Ubuntu and I installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04. I wanted to install code block  and heard from a friend that I should look for it on Software Center.

I tried searching for it on the Software Center and got it but I couldn't figure out how to install it, and also Software center icon is missing. Please help me since I am new to it.

Comment: Could you please  try again after opening a terminal and running: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Comment: MATE uses the Boutique: http://askubuntu.com/questions/797522/how-do-i-search-in-ubuntu-mates-software-boutique